# ATMega32u4 output power to input without external resistor?

Tags: resistors, atmega, output, input

I am new to electronics and have a SparkFun Pro Micro clone with an ATMEGA microcontroller. I wanted to know if I could set one pin to be an output that sends power to another pin that I have set as an input without using an external resistor. Will this cause any issues, such as frying the chip?

Comment: That is indeed how all digital circuits work. The output of one gate (or microcontroller, or any digital output) connects to the input of another.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Your preface isn't particularly necessary, but thank you for the context. Connecting an output to an input should be just fine, but a protection resistor might be advisable if you could set both pins to be outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can drive a High Impedance (Hi-Z) input directly from a General Purpose Output (or GPIO) pin without a resistor. Neither a pull-up or series resistor is ***required***.

The only concern is that you must ***never ever*** switch that input pin to output high or output low. If you do,  you'd create a dead short, burning one or both pins, their pin ports, the microcontroller, the regulator, power supply, etc.

A series resistor is useful to prevent this from happening, by keeping any accidental short to a few mA, not Amps. **At a few cents**, it's cheaper than your clone board. 10k to 47k ohms or so is fine.

Comment: OK, I plan on having the pins constantly switch from being input or output. So, can you possibly explain this a little bit more in detail?

Comment: So that specific pin you want to use as an input to an output, then series resistors are highly recommended.

Comment: @brandon see 1 and 2 here http://www.rugged-circuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/

Answer (score -2):

There are "pull-up" resistors that can be connected to a pin that are usually in the 50K range that will "pull-up" the pin to the digital supply.

But this is generally not applicable to an output. You want to engage the pull-up resistor on the *input* and just drive that input with the output.

So for INPUT pin do:

pinMode(pin, INPUT)
digitalWrite(pin, HIGH)
...
digitalRead(pin)

and for OUTPUT just drive it:

pinMode(pin, OUTPUT)
...
digitalWrite(pin, ...)

Comment: The pull up will do nothing in this case except waste power when the output is low...